# How to seed large data sets faster in laravel using faker

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

I'm seeding 25000 records into 1 table using laravel faker and model factories  and it takes close to 30 minutes to complete and that just delays my productivity. is there a way to seed such large datasets in a much lesser time. like a minute.

This is the Model Factory

```
<?php

use App\Models\Client\Client;
use Faker\Generator;

$factory->define(Client::class, function (Generator $faker) {

    $employeecount  = [15,48,5,12,26,30];
    $numbers        = [0125554,0145755,0123456,8874545,4512156];
    $gross          = [25000,13500,10000,8500,5000,15000,30000];
    $gender         = ['Male','Female'];
    $marketing      = ['E-mail','SMS','Telephone'];
    $maritalstatus  = ['Single','Married','Divorced','Widow'];
    $maritaltype    = ['COP','ANC'];
    $addresstype    = ['Owner','Rent'];
    $serviceused    = ['Status Insight','Credit Union'];
    $riskstatus     = ['Low Risk','Medium Risk','High Risk'];
    $companytype    = ['Public Company','CC','Partnership','Sole Trader','PTY','TLD','Other'];



    return [
        'name'             =>$faker->firstName,
        'surname'          =>$faker->lastName,
        'idnumber'         =>$faker->unique()->ean8,
        'gender'           =>$gender[array_rand($gender)],
        'maritalstatus'    =>$maritalstatus[array_rand($maritalstatus)],
        'maritaltype'      =>$maritaltype[array_rand($maritaltype)],
        'maidenname'       =>$faker->lastName,
        'companytype'      =>$companytype[array_rand($companytype)],
        'companyname'      =>$faker->company,
        'businessnature'   =>$faker->catchPhrase,
        'vatnumber'        =>$numbers[array_rand($numbers)],
        'coregnumber'      =>$numbers[array_rand($numbers)],
        'tradingname'      =>$faker->bs,
        'employeecount'    =>$employeecount[array_rand($employeecount)],
        'employer'         =>$faker->company,
        'gross'            =>$gross[array_rand($gross)],
        'mobilenumber'     =>$numbers[array_rand($numbers)],
        'homenumber'       =>$numbers[array_rand($numbers)],
        'worknumber'       =>$numbers[array_rand($numbers)],
        'email'            =>$faker->email,
        'marketing'        =>$marketing[array_rand($marketing)],
        'physicaladd1'     =>$faker->streetAddress,
        'physicaladd2'     =>$faker->streetName,
        'physicalcity'     =>$faker->city,
        'physicalcode'     =>str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, 4) - 1), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT),
        'yearsAtAddress'   =>str_pad(rand(0, pow(4, 2) - 1), 2),
        'monthsAtAddress'  =>str_pad(rand(0, pow(4, 2) - 1), 2),
        'addresstype'      =>$addresstype[array_rand($addresstype)],
        'postaladd1'       =>$faker->streetAddress,
        'postaladd2'       =>$faker->streetName,  
        'postalcity'       =>$faker->city,
        'postalcode'       =>str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, 4) - 1), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT),
        'riskstatus'       =>$riskstatus[array_rand($riskstatus)],
        'noofjudgements'   =>str_pad(rand(0, pow(2, 2) - 1), 2),
        'noofdefaults'     =>str_pad(rand(0, pow(2, 2) - 1), 2),
        'dateofenquiry'    =>$faker->date($format = 'Y-m-d', $max = 'now'),
        'serviceused'      =>$serviceused[array_rand($serviceused)],

    ];

});
```

This is the Table seeder

```
<?php

use App\Models\Client\Client;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ClientTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(Client::class, 25000)->create();
    }
}
```

And this is the Main Seeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

/**
 * Class DatabaseSeeder.
 */

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

         $this->call(ClientTableSeeder::class);

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

Anyone with a better solution ? 
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Factories is not the way to go in this case in my long experience.
The solution I found working way faster than Factory is Seeder.
What I do is create a huge Collection of data, like 25000~50000 records.
Then use Collection::chunk to Insert (not create) many (500 ~ 1000+) records at once.
Ultimately reducing the number queries thus time.

e.g.

```
        $collectionToInsert = collect([]);
    
        $numberOfEntries = 25000;

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfEntries; $i++) {
            $collectionToInsert->push([
                'name' => $faker->firstName,
                'surname' => $faker->lastName,
                'idnumber' => $faker->unique()->ean8,
                // ...
            ]);
        }
        
        $chunks = $collectionToInsert->chunk(500);
        
         foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
             SomeModel::insert($chunk->toArray());
         }
```

Comment: This might be good for a single table, but what if you have nested relationships? This is only a good example for single table without relations

Answer (score 0):

for big data we have 2 solution:
1- : create a csv file and use "LOAD IN FILE" MYSQL command.
https://www.mockaroo.com/ can help to create fake csv

2- I used

```
for($i=0 ; $i< 6000 ; $i++){
        $records = AhrefRecord::factory()->count(1000)->make();
        $chunks = $records->chunk(500);
        foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
            AhrefRecord::insert($chunk->toArray());
        }
    }
```

for making 60m records and make my insertion 10 times faster. Just chose chunk and "for statement" depends on your php.ini memory_limit.

notice: for relationship insert I handled manually:
I had a relation between ahref_table and ahref_records_table
first I insert 800 records in ahref_table
then I insert 60m records for second table( ahref_records_table ) with random foreign id between 1 to 800

Answer (score -3):

Try and use this . It will help

composer require fzaninotto/faker --dev